# datasource, getting every connection

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have to trace Oracle sessions connected in Java web server as a datasource bean.

Let's say, in spring framework, there is a bean:

```
&lt;bean id="datasource" class="...SimpleDriverDataSource"&gt;...&lt;/bean&gt;
```

And I have to call below PL/SQL on every connections of the pool.

```
begin
    dbms_monitor.serv_mod_act_trace_enable(
        service_name => 'xe'
        module_name => 'javaweb'
        action_name => 'check performance'
        waits => true,
        binds => true
    );
end;
/
```

How do I do this?

Please tell me how to do in mybatis or jdbc.

Thanks

Comment: You should create a logon trigger to do that.

Comment: wow, good idea. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_monitor.htm#CFAGCHJC) this procedure doesn't need to be executed by each session. You'd only have the DBA call it once to enable tracing for a given service, module and action.

Edit: for a more convenient way to check the performance of your XE database I suggest you have a look at the excellent [lab128](http://www.lab128.com) tool.

Comment: I resolved this issue, dbcp connection pool has a property named "connectionInitSqls" that accepts an array of SQLs to call on load